# Footprint unclear part

Tags: footprint

I am trying to draw a footprint of some component which has 8 pins but in the document they shared for outline dimensions and footprint:
[Outline dimensions](https://www.richtek.com/assets/podfiles/POD-PSOP-8.pdf)
[Footprint](https://www.richtek.com/assets/podfiles/Footprint-PSOP-8.pdf)

There is some rectangle in the middle of the footprint. That has sx and sy dimensions. That part confused my mind. Is it silkscreen?

Comment: It's not silkscreen, it's probably a thermal pad. The datasheet of the part should have instructions as to how to connect it (usually GND or NC/float)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

It's a thermal pad to improve heat conductivity thus allowing the device to operate with higher electrical powers. Check the data sheet of the actual part.